# Units in a finite ring

Tags: finite-rings

Let $A$ be a finite unital ring and let $N$ be the set of nonunits of $A$. I want to show that if $|N|>1$ then $\sqrt{|A|}\leq |N|$.   I have tried to find an injective function from $A$ to $N$, but  I don't know anything about whether $A$ is commutative or not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that every left or right divisor in your ring is a nonunit. Now follow the reasoning of [this paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0171&DMDID=DMDLOG_0017). Don't get afraid, the argument is quite elementary.